# Polynomials over Finite Fields.

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, polynomials, solution-verification, problem-solving

I have $f(x)\equiv g(x) \mod p$ where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are polynomial in $x$. $p$ is prime number. Now, given $f(x)$, How to find $g(x)$. What is the procedure (or) bulitin function in Maple software?

Comment: The procedure is not doing it.

Comment: Assuming you are talking about integer polynomials and $f$ is given, there are infinitely many $g$ satisfying $f \equiv g \bmod p$. Which one should an algorithm give you? You could ask for example that $g$ has only positive coefficients smaller than $p$, but this is a particular choice.

Comment: Suppose my f(x) is x^6+1 and prime p=13, then how to find g. Yes integer polynomials.

Comment: Here are some possibilities. $g$ could be: $x^6+1$, $x^6+14, x^6+26x^5 - 39x^3 + 1, x^6 + 13x^{1000}+1$, and I will stop there. However, if you are coding something and you obtained $f$ by using some built-in functions on your computer algebra system, sometimes they have a built-in "lift" procedure, who will give you a natural candidate for $g$.